# WEEK_IN_MONTH(DateTime) not working

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I'm trying to retrieve some records by applying a filter for weeks(for a selected month). To doing this I'm using `WEEEK_IN_MONTH(dateTimeField)` SOQL function. But when this filter applied, result set getting empty. Appreciate any help on this. 

Below is my Dynamic query. It's giving records without the `WEEK_IN_MONTH(dateTimeField) IN :selectedWeek` part.

`SELECT field1, field2, dateTimeField FROM my_Obj WHERE dateTimeField=THIS_YEAR AND CALENDAR_MONTH(dateTimeField) :selectedMonth AND WEEK_IN_MONTH(dateTimeField) IN :selectedWeek`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me community, it's my bad. Just realized that `WEEK_IN_MONTH(dateTime)` is not returning the calendar week of the month. Instead it's returning a number based on, day 1 - day 7 is week 1 and so on. [Date Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)